# Android arrayadapter without specifying object

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

i want to use `listview` with `ArrayAdapter`

After scanning for WiFi, the code for broadcast receiver is as below

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        scanResultDevices.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        wifiResults = wm.getScanResults();
        scanResultDevices = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        scanResultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ScanResult>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        Log.e("inside","BD REceiver");
        if(wifiResults != null){
            for(ScanResult s : wifiResults){
                scanResultAdapter.add(s);
                scanResultDevices.add(s.SSID);
            }
        scanResult.setAdapter(scanResultDevices);
        scanResultDevices.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        unregisterReceiver(scanComp);
    }
```

But this shows null pointer exception at `scanResult.setAdapter(scanResultDevices)`

I know how to use `new ArrayAdapter<T>(context, textViewResourceId, objects)`. But in this specific case i want to try `new ArrayAdapter<T>(context, textViewResourceId)`. If  what i am trying is not possible, then how can i do it correctly?

### EDIT:

Updated code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.dialogtitle);
    scanResult = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);

    //scanResult.setAdapter(scanResultDevices);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Scan For Device").setCustomTitle(v).setPositiveButton("SCan",this).create();
    builder.show();
}
```

The code for onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(!wm.isWifiEnabled()){
        wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turning on Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.e("Wifi","Not-on!Enabling");
    }
    MyDialogFragment alert = new MyDialogFragment();
    alert.show(getFragmentManager(), "SCAN_DIALOG");
    wm.startScan();

    registerReceiver(scanComp, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));


//  if(wifiResults.isEmpty())

}
```

Comment: where is  `scanResult` initialized

Comment: initialized in onCreate, which is a listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible simply:

```
ArrayAdapter<YOUR_CLASS> name =   new ArrayAdapter<YOUR_CLASS>(context, textViewResourceId);
```

And then in api above level 11

```
name.addAll(YOUR_OBJECTS_COLLECTION);
```

or below

```
 for(Class item_name: collection){
 name.add(item_name);
 }
```

A [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.

You should init scanResult in onReceive method

Comment: i want to display the ScanResult got from WifiManager's startScan() in a Alert Dialog as list of available wifi ap names

Comment: You answered what i asked for!! But the problem actually i get null exception is, finViewByid returns null for the listview. Why could it be?

Comment: Beacouse onReceive method can be called without active activity. You need to start the activity when you get notification in onReceive method and pass needed variables by intent

Comment: Activity already started, and except `scanResult` every other is valid.

Comment: Check if findViewById in onCreate method also returns null?

Comment: Yes it's null on OnCreate! I read in SO, that findViewById will only look for widgets only from xml file used in setContentView, i.e that xml file should be processed in onStart, so how should i process the xml file in onStart?

Comment: First of all try in eclipse: Project -> clean and select your project. Then double check if id of view in xml matches id in code. If this not help please post all code of both xml and corresponding java file.